# CSS checkbox hack without for=

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with the checkbox hack to show and hide a list of external links, without using `for=` and JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<label class="tog">
  <input type="checkbox" class="tog-check">
  <div class="tog-list">
    <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
    <div class="tog-less">
      hide
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tog-more">
    show
  </div>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
label.tog{
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input.tog-check{
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
div.tog-list{
  display:none;
}
input.tog-check:checked ~ div.tog-list {
  display:block;
}
input.tog-check:checked ~ div.tog-more {
  display:none;
}
input.tog-check:unchecked ~ div.tog-more {
  display:block;
}
input.tog-check:unchecked ~ div.tog-list {
  display:none;
}
div.tog-list a{
  display:block;
  padding:8px 4px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}
.tog-more, .tog-less{
  padding:8px 4px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}
```

You can see [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/4jzns/). But this is invalid HTML as flow content is not allowed inside labels.

Is it possible to have `.tog-list` outside the label but still have show/hide functionality? Or am I stuck to using `for=`? Or is there some way around this?

Comment: What's the problem with using a `for` attribute?

Comment: The code would be used multiple times on the same page. I'd like something that is re-usable without having to create IDs each time.

Comment: I had considered radio buttons but they would still need some form of ID, I believe.

Comment: You can use jquery to do this very easily. What is the issue with using it?

Comment: I would like this feature to work without JavaScript. I'm aware of how to do it in jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a very old question but I just happened upon it and it piqued my interest.

You don't have to have it all in a label, just position the input *over* the show/hide elements.

E.G

```css
.tog{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  color:#ccc;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight:normal;
  margin:0;
}
.tog * {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.tog-check {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:2.5em;
  opacity:0.00015;
  outline:1px solid red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.tog div {
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height:100px;
}
.tog-list {
  transition:0.5s;
}
.tog .tog-list,
.tog .tog-less,
.tog .tog-check:checked ~ .tog-more {
  max-height:0px;
}
.tog .tog-check:checked ~ .tog-list,
.tog .tog-check:checked ~ .tog-less {
  max-height:100px;
}
.tog-list a,
.tog-more,
.tog-less {
  display:block;
  padding:0px 4px;
  line-height:2em;
}
.tog-list a{
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="tog">
  <input type="checkbox" class="tog-check" />
  <div class="tog-list">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tog-less">[-] less</div>
  <div class="tog-more">[+] more</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4jzns/5/

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment, but I've realised both our fiddles have problems with the hyperlinks.

Comment: Ooh weird. On mobile myself too. JsFiddle is difficult to work with on a mobile (SO is not much better). I'll take a look at this on my desktop tomorrow. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This is normal behaviour for jsfiddle which forbids you from opening a link within the main frame. Makes sense really. If you add `target="blank"` to the link it works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/4jzns/6/

Comment: Ah, I don't remember that limitation before. The only other issue is on mobile, when you tap a link, it highlights the entire menu